# SoapUI Mock Services Dispatching

Tags: mocking, soapui

I have one SoapUI Mock service with multiple responses. I want to send only one response each time the request is received (not all responses in sequence or random). There is not that option in dispatch.
How this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Script, the simplest way is just to return some response:

```
return "Response1"
```

or some more complex script that would return response depending on some value from request.